# Compare a custom type in OCaml

Tags: unit-testing, compare, ocaml

I created my own type

```
type mine = int * int
```

I created a constructor

```
val cons: int -> int -> mine
```

Now I'd like to write a couple of unit tests checking whether constructor creates what I expect

```
open OUnit2;;
let tst _ = assert_equal (7, 15) (Foo.cons 14 45)
```

But then the compiles compares about types (expected `int*int` but got `Foo.mine`. But in fact it's the same type.

Is it possible to compare two such values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type definition like `type mine = int * int` is just an abbreviation. So nothing in principle prevents the comparison.

```
# type mine = int * int;;
type mine = int * int
# let cons a b : mine = (a, b);;
val cons : int -> int -> mine = <fun>
# compare (3, 3) (cons 3 3);;
- : int = 0
```

So, the essence is in the interface of your module `Foo`.

Comment: Hmm... In the interface the type is abstract: `type mine`, and I define it inside the implementation

Comment: Exactly. If you make the type abstract it's no longer the same type as `int * int`. This is a good thing. Whether you want to violate the abstraction in your testing is the question. You could provide a comparison function inside the module.